# Remove particular object from jsonb[] using index in stored procedure postgresql

Tags: stored-procedures, postgresql-10

Here is my jsonb[] data.

```
{"{\"status\": 0, \"category\": \"Workout\", \"workoutId\": 655, \"workoutType\": \"card\", \"workoutTypeId\": 10, \"creatorstrengthPgmId\": 0}","{\"status\": 0, \"category\": \"Workout\", \"workoutId\": 23, \"workoutType\": \"card\", \"workoutTypeId\": 10, \"creatorstrengthPgmId\": 0}"}
```

I need to remove particular jsonb from this jsonb[] using index value. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, my mistake. Does have any method in postgresql 10 ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove? Note that `jsonb[]` is usually a bad choice to begin with, a JSON array inside a `jsonb` column would have been the better thing to do.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Im not sure about the  data which I have provided is jsonb[] or not. How can we remove an item from the above using index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As you said "array inside a jsonb column" is better option. Then how can we remove a particular jsonb from array using index ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How can we remove a particular jsonb from array using index ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need to remove {\"status\": 0, \"category\": \"Workout\", \"workoutId\": 655, \"workoutType\": \"card\", \"workoutTypeId\": 10, \"creatorstrengthPgmId\": 0}    

from

 {"{\"status\": 0, \"category\": \"Workout\", \"workoutId\": 655, \"workoutType\": \"card\", \"workoutTypeId\": 10, \"creatorstrengthPgmId\": 0}","{\"status\": 0, \"category\": \"Workout\", \"workoutId\": 23, \"workoutType\": \"card\", \"workoutTypeId\": 10, \"creatorstrengthPgmId\": 0}"}

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove?